# berkeley db save into disk

Tags: c, berkeley-db

I am a newbie in berkeley db, when I create a db in this way:

```
DB *dbp;

db_create(&dbp, NULL, 0);


dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &key, &data, 0);
```

Do I store the data into the disk? If so, where is the database file? As far as I know, only when I create a database environment using `DB_ENV->open()` and specify the parameter `char *db_home` do I store into a real file, am I right? Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Berkeley DB spec;

> To open a database, you must first use the db_create() function to initialize a DB handle. Once you have initialized the DB handle, you use its open() method to open the database.
>   Note that *by default, DB does not create databases if they do not already exist.* To override this behavior, specify the **DB_CREATE** flag on the **open()** method.

```
#include <db.h> 

//...

DB *dbp;           /* DB structure handle */
u_int32_t flags;   /* database open flags */
int ret;           /* function return value */

/* Initialize the structure. This
 * database is not opened in an environment, 
 * so the environment pointer is NULL. */
ret = db_create(&dbp, NULL, 0);
if (ret != 0) {
  /* Error handling goes here */
}

/* Database open flags */
flags = DB_CREATE;    /* If the database does not exist, 
                       * create it.*/

/* open the database */
ret = dbp->open(dbp,        /* DB structure pointer */
                NULL,       /* Transaction pointer */
                "my_db.db", /* On-disk file that holds the database. */
                NULL,       /* Optional logical database name */
                DB_BTREE,   /* Database access method */
                flags,      /* Open flags */
                0);         /* File mode (using defaults) */
if (ret != 0) {
  /* Error handling goes here */
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_05/html/gsg/C/databases.html#DBOpen

Comment: I would add that piling's answer illustrates an important concept: it captures the return codes and handles errors.  @HuangJie, if you had done that, you would have seen an error from the **put** function that would have told you *at least* that it didn't work, and possibly have led you to open the database first.